# Is it possible to exclude a class from SASS import?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

I have a site where bootstrap styles are imported through SASS. For example -

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/carousel';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/dropdown';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/forms';
```

There is one page with a lot of conflicting style names. Instead of overriding the individual styles, is it possible to have a :not rule or something similar? Something like -

```
:not(.className) {
  @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot';
}
```